# Which characters were at the wedding in Rocky Horror?

Tags: the-rocky-horror-picture-show

In *Rocky Horror Picture Show* we see Dr. Frank N. Furter in the wedding pictures. Were any other characters whom we see later also at the wedding? Who?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If we broaden the scope from "in the wedding picture" to "in the wedding scene", we have:

### The obvious - Frank, Riff-Raff, and Magenta in the photo:

[image]

---

### Other Transylvanians in the photo:

Since the other Transylvanians don't have names, I'll use the names of the actors who play them.

[image]

[image] [image]
[image]

---

### Transylvanians (played by Perry Bedden and Henry Woolf) taking the photo:

[image] [image]

---

### Other Transylvanians in the scene:

[image]

[image][image]

[image][image]
[image]

[image][image]
[image][image]

---

### Columbia joins Frank, Riff-Raff, and Magenta in the chapel:

[image]

---

### Riff-Raff and Magenta recreate [Grant Wood's painting *American Gothic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Gothic) in this scene;  we see the actual painting later:

[image]
[image]

---

### Riff-Raff's pitchfork may become the anti-matter laser gun with which he kills Frank, Columbia, and Rocky:

[image]
[image]

---

*Note:  The [Sweet Transvestites](http://www.sweet-transvestites.com/uk/RHPS/Bios/trannies-uk.htm) website was extremely useful for this answer.*

Answer (score 8):

In the opening wedding scene the minister is Tim Curry **(Dr. Frank N. Furter)**, the “old man” to his left is Richard O’Brien **(Riff Raff)** and the “wife” to his right is Patricia Quinn **(Magenta)**.

[image]

Comment: Of course we can only verify that these are the same _actors_ we don't know if these are also the same _characters_

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure that is what the OP was implying since the answer was accepted. :)

Comment: @steelerfan that was indeed what I was getting at - apologies if it was unclear. I didn't even realize the other two were there - it's still even hard to tell that's Magenta!

Comment: @Howdy_McGee No need for apologies.  I completely understood what you were implying :)

Comment: And Brad and Janet, of course.

Comment: @R.J.MacReady But, they weren't in this picture.  I read the question as the OP wanted to know who was at the wedding (pictured) that we see later in the film.  Of course Brad and Janet were there, just not in this picture...unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

When Brad is singing to Janet in the chapel, the people changing it from a wedding to a funeral are Riff Raff, Magenta and Columbia.  Always heard a rumor that all the guests to Rocky's "coming out party" were also at the wedding, but I never watched it close enough to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Kimi Wong is also at the wedding.

Comment: It might be helpful if you mention where exactly Kimi is like the accepted answer.

Comment: She’s the girl with the black hair and pigtails on the left waving goodbye. White shoes, gloves and socks, and holding the younger boy’s hand.

Comment: Also, the tall young man on the right with short hair, waving goodbye is Stephen Calcutt.

Comment: As far as I can tell, only 4 Transylvanians present at the lab were not at Ralph and Betty’s wedding; the lady with the afro, the man with the platinum wig, the man with the turban, and the dwarf lady.